# how to add space in start when add image in button

Tags: android

how do I add some space when adding image in button? this is my code below and the image is [URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2trZa.jpg) which show image button and text on the button but the image shows left most side of the button.

I want to add some space in the start of the image like this image which [URL is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u5GI.jpg).

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"   
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/MyAccountbutton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dip"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Handshake"
            android:background="@drawable/curvedplanebutton"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Payments"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` , `android:drawablePadding="10dip"` and `android:paddingLeft="10dip"` should do the trick.. If not then just create a Custom Layout for both view Image and Text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some `android:drawablePadding` so that image will have some space. Change your button code with below code:

```
<Button   android:id="@+id/MyAccountbutton"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dip"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Handshake"
             android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/curvedplanebutton"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Payments"/>
```

Comment: thnx is work what about text?  there is much distance between text and image how to i reduce space??

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:drawablePadding="16dip"` and `android:paddingLeft="16dip"` to the `Button`.

Comment: thnx is work what about text? there is much distance between text and image how to i reduce space??

Comment: you should reduce `android:layout_marginRight="35dip"` and `android:layout_marginLeft="35dip"`. please vote up.

Comment: no  if i reduce margin on right and left button size is large i dont want to increse button size only reduce space between image and text